# JavaFx how to align only one column-header in tableview?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-css

How to align title of only one column in tableview?
The following css aligns all column-header but I want to align just one column:

```
.table-view .column-header .label{
    -fx-alignment:CENTER
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do that now with recent versions of JavaFX.

**Java 1.7**

This worked for me with Java: 1.7.0_45 / JavaFX: 2.2.45-b18). It should be a recent version because it requires [RT-14909](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-14909?focusedCommentId=277397&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-277397)

The column-header will automatically get the same "Id" as the TableColumn! Therefore your TableColumn(s) need an (CSS-) Id that you can either set in Scenebuilder for the TableColumn directly or use some code like `tableColumn.setId("my-special-column")`.

Then you can style the column-header directly using the Id:

```
.table-view .column-header#my-special-column .label {
  -fx-alignment: CENTER_RIGHT;
  -fx-text-fill: red;
}
```

PS: This took me some frustrating 1,5 hours to figure out. Hope this helps others now!

**Java 8**

For reasons that I don't understand the id trick does not work for Java 8 anymore. However, what we can do is to set a styleClass for the column directly (which internally is propagated to the TableColumnHeader) and change this styleClass in the css file:

In Java:

```
firstNameCol.getStyleClass().add("my-special-column-style");
```

And in CSS:

```
.my-special-column-style .label {
  -fx-alignment: CENTER_RIGHT;
  -fx-text-fill: red;
}
```

Works for me here with jdk1.8.0_05 on Mac OS X.

Comment: Yes, for reasons that are beyond me they changed it in Java 8 :/ But I've edited my answer with a proper solution for Java 8.

Answer (score 3):

I stuggled with this myself, but found this solution. This will right align a single column whereas the rest of the columns in the same table are left aligned:

In code:

```
myCol.getStyleClass().add("rightAlignedTableColumnHeader");
```

In CSS:

```
.column-header.rightAlignedTableColumnHeader > .label {
    -fx-alignment: center-right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions worked for me (not sure why).  I am using jdk1.8.0_66 on Windows.

This is a bit of a hack, but it works:

```
// Hack: align column headers to the center.  
table.widthProperty().addListener((src, o, n) -> Platform.runLater(() -> {
  if (o != null && o.intValue() > 0) return; // already aligned
  for (Node node: table.lookupAll(".column-header > .label")) {
    if (node instanceof Label) ((Label)node).setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
  }    
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

@DOM
@void256 for what it is worth I tried your code and it works fine. I also tried this code and it works what the puzzle is I had to use top-left as the CENTER_RIGHT would not work. I am using jre 1.8.0_45 with eclipse luna
The other strange issue is if you set this in Scene Builder it does not work on the header text but on the column text

```
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    firstNameColumn.getStyleClass().add("top-left");
    lastNameColumn.getStyleClass().add("any-this-works-here;");
    phoneNumberColumn.getStyleClass().add("top-left;");
    emailAddressColumn.getStyleClass().add("top-left;");
}


.table-view .column-header .label{
    -fx-font-size: 12pt;
    -fx-text-fill: blue;
    -fx-alignment:top-left;

}
```